# TableView into ScrollView - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I would like to insert a `UITableView` into a `UIScrollView`.
To do this I added a ContainerView inside the `UIScrollView` and a `UITableView` linked to this `ContainerView`.

The result obtained in the storyboard is this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hZz.jpg (Storyboard)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGY4L.jpg (Storyboard)

When I launch the emulator the TableView is loaded correctly, but not with the result expected

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebij9.gif (Animated GIF)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEO8B.jpg (Wrong result)

But instead what I wanted to to obtain is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Zhb.jpg

Is it possible?
Could you tell me if the way to proceed is correct?
Thanks!!

I have not enough reputation to post images and more than two links.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Is the tableview height fixed or are you going to re-size the tableview height depending upon the number of cells?

Comment: If its fixed than in viewWillAppear you can update the container view's height equal to the tableview's height.

Comment: @PradeepSingh : No i'm going to resize the tableview depending upon the number of cells. The number of cells is from 0 to 5 and each cell may have a different height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you have is close, but you need to set the size of the container view to the content size of the table view once it has loaded its data. Your other views around the content view then need to respond to the change in size so you don't get overlaps.

If you know the height of each row in the table and how many there are then it's easiest to calculate the hight required and set that as the size of the content view. If you don't, or the height can change based on user choices or something like that, then you will need to do something more complicated which observes the content size of the table view and updates things when it changes.

Comment: I'll try what you advise me to do, but i can't figured out. I try to make things simple: i just want to resize the container view runtime. I created a property to container view: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *cont;` and in `viewWillAppear` i try to change the height: `CGRect frame = _cont.frame; frame.size.height = 500; _cont.frame = frame;` but does not work. where I am wrong?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes. I messed up the project, so i created a new one. I created a `IBOutlet` for the constraint relative to the height of the ContainerView. Now everything is working correctly. Thanks.